# Given an array of integers of size n+1 consisting of the elements [1,n]. All elements are unique except one which is duplicated k times

Tags: arrays, algorithm, duplicates

I have been attempting to solve the following problem:

You are given an array of `n+1` integers where all the elements lies in `[1,n]`. You are also given that one of the elements is duplicated a certain number of times, whilst the others are distinct. Develop an algorithm to find both the duplicated number and the number of times it is duplicated.

Here is my solution where I let k = number of duplications:

```
struct LatticePoint{ // to hold duplicate and k
   int a;
   int b;
   LatticePoint(int a_, int b_) : a(a_), b(b_) {}
   }
   
LatticePoint findDuplicateAndK(const std::vector<int>& A){

int n = A.size() - 1;
std::vector<int> Numbers (n);

for(int i = 0; i < n + 1; ++i){
   ++Numbers[A[i] - 1]; // A[i] in range [1,n] so no out-of-access
   }
   
int i = 0;
while(i < n){
   if(Numbers[i] > 1) {
      int duplicate = i + 1;
      int k = Numbers[i] - 1;
      LatticePoint result{duplicate, k};
      return LatticePoint;
}
```

So, the basic idea is this: we go along the array and each time we see the number `A[i]` we increment the value of `Numbers[A[i]]`. Since only the duplicate appears more than once, the index of the entry of Numbers with value greater than 1 must be the duplicate number with the value of the entry the number of duplications - 1. This algorithm of `O(n)` in time complexity and `O(n)` in space.

I was wondering if someone had a solution that is better in time and/or space? (or indeed if there are any errors in my solution...)

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the scratch space to `n` bits instead of `n` `int`s, provided you either have or are willing to write a `bitset` with run-time specified size (see `boost::dynamic_bitset`).

You don't need to collect duplicate counts until you know which element is duplicated, and then you only need to keep that count. So all you need to track is whether you have previously seen the value (hence, `n` bits). Once you find the duplicated value, set `count` to 2 and run through the rest of the vector, incrementing `count` each time you hit an instance of the value. (You initialise `count` to 2, since by the time you get there, you will have seen exactly two of them.)

That's still O(n) space, but the constant factor is a lot smaller.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of your code works.

But, thanks to the `n+1` elements, we can achieve other tradeoffs of time and space.

If we have some number of buckets we're dividing numbers between, putting `n+1` numbers in means that some bucket has to wind up with more than expected.  This is a variant on the well-known [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

So we use 2 buckets, one for the range `1..floor(n/2)` and one for `floor(n/2)+1..n`.  After one pass through the array, we know which half the answer is in.  We then divide that half into halves, make another pass, and so on.  This leads to a binary search which will get the answer with `O(1)` data, and `with ceil(log_2(n))` passes, each taking time `O(n)`. Therefore we get the answer in time `O(n log(n))`.

Now we don't need to use 2 buckets.  If we used 3, we'd take `ceil(log_3(n))` passes.  So as we increased the fixed number of buckets, we take more space and save time.  Are there other tradeoffs?

Well you showed how to do it in 1 pass with `n` buckets.  How many buckets do you need to do it in 2 passes?  The answer turns out to be at least `sqrt(n)` bucekts.  And 3 passes is possible with the cube root.  And so on.

So you get a whole family of tradeoffs where the more buckets you have, the more space you need, but the fewer passes.  And your solution is merely at the extreme end, taking the most spaces and the least time.

Comment: I don't understand.  We don't know which number is duped in advance.  If we divide the array in say 2 or 3 or 4 sub-arrays, what if each subarray contains a single occurrence of the same element?  How will we know the dup, how will we know k (the count of that dup)?

Comment: @danh It isn't divide the array into subarrays.  It is to divide the possible range into subranges. And then we count how many are in each subrange. The subranges without the special element won't have more than the length of the subrange elements. The subrange with the special element WILL have more than the length of the subrange elements.  And now that you know the subrange it is in, you repeat with smaller subranges.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cheekier algorithm, which requires only constant space but rearranges the input vector. (It only reorders; all the original elements are still present at the end.)

It's still O(n) time, although that might not be completely obvious.
The idea is to try to rearrange the array so that A[i] is i, until we find the duplicate. The duplicate will show up when we try to put an element at the right index and it turns out that that index already holds that element. With that, we've found the duplicate; we have a value we want to move to A[j] but the same value is already at A[j]. We then scan through the rest of the array, incrementing the count every time we find another instance.

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
std::pair<int, int> count_dup(std::vector<int> A) {
  /* Try to put each element in its "home" position (that is,
   * where the value is the same as the index). Since the
   * values start at 1, A[0] isn't home to anyone, so we start
   * the loop at 1.
   */
  int n = A.size();
  for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    while (A[i] != i) {
      int j = A[i];
      if (A[j] == j) {
        /* j is the duplicate. Now we need to count them.
         * We have one at i. There's one at j, too, but we only
         * need to add it if we're not going to run into it in
         * the scan. And there might be one at position 0. After that,
         * we just scan through the rest of the array.
         */
        int count = 1;
        if (A[0] == j) ++count;
        if (j < i) ++count;
        for (++i; i < n; ++i) {
          if (A[i] == j) ++count;
        }
        return std::make_pair(j, count);
      }
      /* This swap can only happen once per element. */
      std::swap(A[i], A[j]);
    }
  }
  /* If we get here, every element from 1 to n is at home.
   * So the duplicate must be A[0], and the duplicate count
   * must be 2.
   */
  return std::make_pair(A[0], 2);
}
```

Comment: This is nice! (For those who are wondering why its O(n) in time, as I was, its because each while loop puts an element in its "correct" position).

Answer (score 0):

A parallel solution with O(1) complexity is possible.

Introduce an array of atomic booleans and two atomic integers called duplicate and count. First set count to 1. Then access the array in parallel at the index positions of the numbers and perform a test-and-set operation on the boolean. If a boolean is set already, assign the number to duplicate and increment count.

This solution may not always perform better than the suggested sequential alternatives. Certainly not if all numbers are duplicates. Still, it has constant complexity in theory. Or maybe linear complexity in the number of duplicates. I am not quite sure. However, it should perform well when using many cores and especially if the test-and-set and increment operations are lock-free.